# Curving from one point to another

Tags: c++, algorithm, path

I have tiles that are in random spots, and they wind up at x',y' (to make a nice 2d array) by doing :

> X<sub>t</sub> = (((X′-X)/T)*t)+X ,
>   Y<sub>t</sub> = (((Y′-Y)/T)*t)+Y

This works well, but it is linear. I'm looking for something curvier. A little bit like a parabola works. Basically instead of getting to X' in a straight line, I'm looking for an algorithm that will curve out and end up at X' and the amount of curvature is base on a variable.

Thanks

*EDIT
I think Bezier curve look to be what I want, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Could someone please explain the quadratic bezier formula. I'm also unsure what the 'E' - like symbol does. I think it relates to a range but I'm not sure, Thanks

Comment: I figured out what E meant and was able to implement it myself by doing : Nx = (1 - i) ^ 2 * x + 2 * (1 - i) * i * 200 + (i ^ 2) * xP
            Ny = (1 - i) ^ 2 * y + 2 * (1 - i) * i * 900 + (i ^ 2) * yP

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Bezier Curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curves), or some other similar parametric curve.  These are programatically quite easy to code and have the advantage of being intuitively straightforward to manipulate.  The best treatise I know of is in the classic book [Mathematical Elements of Computer Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070535302), but any textbook on computer graphics will probably include a basic introduction.

Comment: You might the add the more simplistic interpolations namely Lagrange and Newton interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a [Catmul-Rom spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline), it's a type of Hermite spline that passes though the control points. Bezier curves are not the way to go, they are difficult to control in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page about Perlin Noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm), in particular the "Interpolation" section.  The general idea is that instead of a linear transfer function over `t` in `[0, 1]`, you can apply something to result in smoother curves.  The "smoothest" noise is a `cos(t)` function, but cubic or quintic polynomials can be used to approximate a cosine.